# Deployment failed case on Devtestlab

Tags: azure-devtest-labs

I am trying to add a claimable VM for my lab in Azure DevTest following this document [Create and manage claimable VMs - Azure DevTest Labs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-add-claimable-vm) but whenever I try to add

```
Operating system = windows
base vm = windows server 2022 datacenter azure editon core 
size  = standard_B1s
```

I am getting failed yet each time I attempt to add

[image: image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmRCb.png)]

And the disk showing as No result

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG4Ip.png)]

Any solution while using this particular data center it fails or am i doing something wrong and I want this particular data center to have a fix for the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

I created ***Devtest lab*** like below:

[image]

To resolve this issue try to add ***Artifact*** to configure and add to the VM like below:

[image]

Select Artifact:

[image]

In Additionally try to set an expiration date that you might want to delete VMs automatically after a certain date so they don't keep incurring costs. To create more than one VM with this configuration select an instancelike below:

[image]

***Now, Deployment is created with disk successfully like below:***

[image]

[image]